# Proof with theorems like mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, logic

This must be a very elementary problem, someone may asked before, I am not much exposed to math, I don't know what keyword to search it.

I'm learning from Spivak's calculus, in Chapter 11, question 28, he asked to prove:

if $f'(x)\le M$, for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, then $f(b)-f(a)\le M(b-a)$.

The answer given in the answer book is:

We have

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(x) \quad for\,some\,x\,in\,(a,b) $$
$$\le M,\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,$$
so $f(b)-f(a)\le M(b-a)$
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Since the mean value theorem states only "for some", then for some function I can choose$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>f'(x)$, even though, I can't prove such case must exist, but would the possibility that such case exist weaker the proof?
And more I want to know is how to make the most use of theorems contain "for some $x$"? What kind of stuff should I read as a math beginner?

Comment: I want to add to @JoseCarlosSantos's nice answer that this is a *great* question to ask, and is exactly the kind of thing that leads to a deeper understanding of the "edge" of theorems, i.e., just what breaks if you leave out one hypothesis. And Jose has done what many working mathematicians would do: he's looked at just about the simplest possible example to see what happens. When you, too, learn to do that, you'll start to get a better feel for things. A statement for which it's tough to find counterexamples is just the kind of thing that *might* be a theorem.

Comment: +1 for the question. And +1 for excellent remarks of @JohnHughes (especially the last sentence).

Comment: Another thing to be cautious of is negated sentences. In everyday speech, people often say "All A are not B" when they mean "Not all A are B". It  is a matter of what word(s) the "not" applies to. E.g, "All  bears are not-white" versus "Not-all bears are white".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course that you can have$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>f'(x)\tag1$$for some other $x$. If, for instance, $f(x)=x^2$, $a=0$, and $b=1$, then we are comparing $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=1$ with $f'(x)=2x$. And, when $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, we have cases in which, in fact, $(1)$ holds: any $x\in\left[0,\frac12\right)$ will do.

That doesn't change two facts:

1. There is **some** $x\in[a,b]$ such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(x)$;
2. For **each** $x\in[a,b]$, $f'(x)\leqslant M$.

Puting all this together, we get that, in fact,$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\leqslant M.$$

Comment: Thank you for helping me many times sir. This question troubled me 24 hours and 1hour even after reading your answer, because when I read your answer and my old note, they seems both make sense. after sometimes, I realize I was mistakenly thought (f(b)-f(a))/ (b-a) is 'moveable', indeed, I can't choose the value of this division after f, a and b are settled, for every (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a) discussed I can choose f'(x).

Comment: I'm glad I could help and I hope that I'll be able to do it again in the future.